# ERROR: Fetching the page failed because it's denied by robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, twitter-card

My robots.txt file details:

```
User-agent: Twitterbot

Disallow:

User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

How to solve this?

Comment: If your agent is disallowed, you are disallowed. There's not a fix short of contacting the site owner and asking them to please allow you to automatically crawl their site.

Comment: is this server side problem for automatically crawl  ..??